# Parallels video memory

Tags: parallels-desktop

I have a new 27" iMac with 1 GB of video card memory. I'm trying to play The Witcher 2 in Parallels. (Boot Camp is just too much of a hassle.)

It appears I can allocate only 256 MB of video memory to the VM?

Is that the limit? Am I out of luck if I want Windows to have more video card memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallels will intelligently cap you at what the Mac OS can operate on, so if that's where it maxes out, and you're running the proper, up to date version of Parallels and Windows, then yes.

You can also make adjustments to the Windows OS itself to free up memory (ie. reduce visual elements and effects).

Comment: This seriously sucks. I can't believe that Mac OS X requires 768MB of video memory just to run the system. It should be possible to reverse the memory allocation (majority goes to Windows VM, the rest to the Host OS). Anyway, same here, Parallels won't let me to assign more. I think I read somewhere that 256MB was the maximum.